# How can I remove a FontAwesome-based background of an alert-box after clicking on the close button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some alert boxes on my website. I need my FontAwesome-based background to disappear when someone clicks on the close button in the upper-right corner of the alert box.

[image: Image of the Alert Box]

My alert box has the following code:

```
<div id="system-message">
    <div class="alert alert-notice">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="">×</a>
        <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning</h4>
            <div>
              <div>blah blah blah.</div>
            </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

And the piece of code that creates the background is this:

```
div#system-message:before {
    position: absolute; top: 30px; right: 100px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: .1;
  content: "\f00c"; z-index: 1;}
```

When I close the alert box, the Font-Awesome background remains visible!
How can I prevent this?
Insert some: after selector in the CSS? But how?

Can some kind soul out there help me out? Cheers.

Comment: _"When I close the alert box..."_ - The background is applied to a pseudo element within `#system-message`, not the `.alert` element.

Comment: I think I was able to solve this. I put the FontAwesome background inside the DIV with the "alert-success" class. Now it closes!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in your CSS the background is attached to `#system-message` that is the parent element. You have to change your code as follow:

```
div#system-message>alert:before {
    position: absolute; top: 30px; right: 100px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: .1;
  content: "\f00c"; z-index: 1;}
```

If you don't want to repeat the background on every alert you can add `:first-child` selector.